How to catch SIGILL when using ptrace syscall tracing?
I'm trying to syscall trace a program (which might contain invalid assembly instructions) using ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, ...), while also handling any SIGILL signals raised.
I would've expected the call to waitpid to return the SIGILL signal (using WSTOPSIG()) in the program below - however, it returns SIGTRAP|0x80 (i.e. syscall-stop)!
This odd behavior does not occur when running with PTRACE_CONT instead.
I'm obviously missing something as gdb is able to differentiate the two signals (using catch syscall), but I'm unsure what that is.
The example code:
void tracee() {
    ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL);
    raise(SIGSTOP);
    asm volatile(".byte 0x0f, 0x0b, 0x0, 0x0");
}

void tracer(pid_t pid) {
    int status;
    waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
    assert(WIFSTOPPED(status) && WSTOPSIG(status) == SIGSTOP);

    ptrace(PTRACE_SETOPTIONS, pid, 0, PTRACE_O_EXITKILL | PTRACE_O_TRACESYSGOOD);
    ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid, 0, 0);
    waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
    printf("stop sig = %d\n", WSTOPSIG(status)); // expected SIGILL, got SIGTRAP|0x80
}

int main() {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) { tracee(); }
    else if (pid > 0) {tracer(pid); }
    return 0;
}

Thanks in advance!
